# Pausing a form submit to wait for a validation in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a form which I can submit using a submit button. When I press this submit button I have it that a popup appears asking for a 'password' (rfid). This is handled by another form which POSTs the password in order to get the verification process handled by PHP. If the password is confirmed I want it to go back and submit the first form so that it POSTs that content. I just can not think of any way to go back to the first forms submit.

The popup is handled by onSubmit="" of the form element and calls a JavaScript function that makes the popup appear.

Those are my two forms:

```html
<form id="klausur" action="php/action_klausur.php" method="post" onSubmit="return getRFID();">
      <div class="selections">
  </p>
     <p><span class="tag">Fach</span>
       <select name="fach" class="minimal">
        <?php
    populate_fach();
   ?>
       </select>
  </p>
     <p><span class="tag">Tag</span>
       <select name="tag" class="minimal">
        <option value="M">Montag</option>
        <option value="D">Dienstag</option>
        <option value="Mi">Mittwoch</option>
        <option value="Do">Donnerstag</option>
        <option value="F">Freitag</option>
       </select>
  </p>
     <p><span class="tag">Block</span>
       <select name="block" class="minimal">
        <option value="1">07:30 - 09:00</option>
        <option value="2">09:25 - 10:55</option>
        <option value="3">11:15 - 12:45</option>
        <option value="4">13:30 - 15:00</option>
        <option value="5">15:15 - 16:45</option>
       </select>
  </p>
     </div>
      <input type="submit" class="block" value="ABSENDEN">
      </form>
```

```html
<form id="rfid_field" action="php/check_rfid.php" method="post">
   <input type="text" name="rfid" id="rfid" class="rfid" autofocus>
  </form>
```

This is the JavaScript snippet making the popup appear:

```js
function getRFID(){
 "use strict";
 var modal = document.getElementById('rfidPopup');
 modal.style.display = "block";
 return false;
}
```

So my question basically is: How can i go back to the first form submission when the password check is positive?

Edit: Addet the PHP Code from the second form that should redirect:

```
<?php
//Fügt die Funktionen der Datei database_con.php hinzu
include 'database_con.php';

//Speichert den Inhalt des RFID Feldes in die Variable $rfid
$rfid = $_POST["rfid"];

//Öffnet eine Verbindung zur Datenbank
open_connection();
global $conn;

$query = "SELECT Lehrer_RFID from Lehrer";
$result = $conn->query($query);
$rows = resultsToArry($result);
//Gibt alle Infos über die Variable aus zum testen
//var_dump($rows);
if(verifyRFID($rfid, $rows)){

}

$result->free();

function resultsToArry($result){
    $rows = array();
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $rows[] = $row;
    }
    return $rows;
}

function verifyRFID($rfid, $rows){
    foreach ($rows as $value) {
        if($value == $rfid) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
?>
```

Comment: Where is PHP code?

Comment: I've added the PHP code from the second form that runs the validation check.

Comment: This can be achieved using jQuery AJAX. The form submit will reload the page when you will submit your pop up form and will destroy previous form data.

Comment: Could u give me a short example on how to implement such a feature using jQuery AJAX? I'm relativeley new to this whole topic and have never worked with AJAX before.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using PHP, the form submit will reload the page. When there is a dependency of one form submit on another, the forms should be submitted Asynchronously. Here jQuery ajax would help

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#rfidPopUpForm").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(submitForm(this)) {
      submitForm($('#mainForm'))
    };
    
  });
  
  function submitForm(form) {
    
    var data = {};
    $.each(form, function(i, v){
        var input = $(v);
        data[input.attr("name")] = input.val();
        delete data["undefined"];
    });
    return $.ajax({
        contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
        type:form.attr("method"),
        url:form.attr("action"),
        dataType:'json',
        data:JSON.stringify(data),
        success:function(data) {
           console.log(data)
        }
    });
  
  }
})
```

**NOTE**: Its not a full-proof solution. Hence do not expect it will run as it is. I have written this by certain assumption.

Hope this helps!

-AG

Comment: Thank you for this snippet! I am pretty sure i understand everything u did there except for one part. What exactly does the part in function submitForm(form) before the return do?
And where would i place it in my project in order to get it triggered?

Comment: `submitForm(form)` will post your form Asynchronously. You can put this code into any JS file and load it into your index. Or to try it only, put this under `<script>` tag into your file where you are trying to perform these operations

Comment: Okay, but i ment this part: `var data = {};
    $.each(form, function(i, v){
        var input = $(v);
        data[input.attr("name")] = input.val();
        delete data["undefined"];
    });`
I dont understand exactly what this is for.

Comment: This is to get all the values of form Inputs and post it to given action

Comment: Thank you. Do I have to change the ("name") to anything specific then?